# set date function foundation datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datepicker

I am using foundation datepicker for startDate and endDate.

1) On clicking of calendar filed, defaultly it is showing the today's date.

2) If I on change any date from startDate, for example If I select "10-10-2016".

3) Next without changing any date from endDate, on clicking of endDate filed it should start as "10-10-2016" only. But it is starting as an today's date.

Please look at this fiddle,

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/du0a6tyu/)

Please see the first image.

[image]

I am selecting "14.07.2016" from startDate.

[image]

On Clicking of endDate, it has starting with today's Date. But it is disabled. It is correct. I want to start with "14.07.2016" only. Blue color active date should show on selected startDate.

[image]

See the last image. Upto "14.07.2016" all dates are disbled. But it is not starting with that date. Please help me how can I do this.

```js
var nowTemp = new Date();
var now = new Date(nowTemp.getFullYear(), nowTemp.getMonth(), nowTemp.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);
var checkin = jQuery('#startDate').fdatepicker({
     format: "dd.mm.yyyy",
   onRender: function (date) {
              return date.valueOf() < now.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
             }
   }).data('datepicker');
      var checkout = jQuery('#endDate').fdatepicker({
          format: "dd.mm.yyyy",
          onRender: function (date) {
              return date.valueOf() < checkin.date.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
          }
   }).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
         checkout.hide();
   }).data('datepicker');
```

```html
<input type="text" id="startDate" name="start_datum" class="input_text date"   value="" >
    
<input type="text" id="endDate" name="end_datum" class="input_text" value="">
```

Comment: Check this updated [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/du0a6tyu/2/)

Comment: without selecting endate, it should be empty. But it automatically populating the startDate. I want that field empty. In calendar only It should show the start date.

Comment: @Pugazh how can I make empty of endDate field. After selecting date fom calenda only i want to display in text field.

Comment: Please anyone tell me the answer.